# Android & Firebase Async tasks

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tenho uma classe `Java` que sobrescrevi o metodo `toString()` dentro desse metodo antes de retornar consulto o fireBase e preencho um objeto. Meu problema é o seguinte o `return` do `toString()` acaba sendo executado antes do firebase ter preenchido o objeto. Como posso dizer a classe para esperar o objeto ser preenchido antes de retornar o mesmo

```
public class exom(){
 private String ID;
 private String horaInicio;
 private String horaFim;
 private String IDEvento;
 // Objeto que deve vir do firebase
 Objeto obj;
  //Getters and setters....
   @Override
   public String toString() {
     FireDB fireDB = new FireDB(null);
     fireDB.getMdatabase().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            obj = child.getValue(Objeto.class);
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

     return horaInicio + " - " + horaFim + " - "+ obj.getNome();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

na realidade não é uma boa pratica você realizar esse tipo de consulta que precisa "esperar" na thread principal. Quanto ao firebase, infelizmente (ou felizmente) ele não possui uma formar sincrona para obter dados.

Você deveria preencher o objeto antes de fazer qualquer comparação com o toString();